# Docker rebuild .Net Core project without removing container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have Docker compose file that run `MySql`, `Redis`, `RabbitMq` and other services with my project on production server connected to the bridge network.

I want to when I change something in code and to be able to make image and rebuild only container that contains my project image. I don't want to stop and rebuild with compose other services and other projects (microservices).

What are the best practices for doing those stuff without touching other containers?

I developing locally, and I see that Visual Studio when I hit run (Docker) - container is not removed, just somehow killed and runned in same container.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for updating the specific container, you need to follow the command below:

```
docker pull mysql
docker stop my-mysql-container
docker rm my-mysql-container
docker run --name=my-mysql-container --restart=always \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd -v /my/data/dir:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql
```

For your request, if you want to update the specific container under `docker-compose`, you could try specifing the `--no-deps` like below

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build servicename
```

For this command, it will only build, run the specific service.

[image]